# Self-normalized martingale central limit theorem

Tags: probability-theory, martingales, central-limit-theorem, probability-limit-theorems

I'd like to know if there exists a martingale central limit theorem of a particular type.

**Theorem (?)** Suppose that  $\{(\xi_{n,k}, \mathcal{F}_{n,k})\}$ are a martingale difference array that satisfies

$$ \frac{\max_{1 \leq k \leq n} |\xi_{n,k}|^2}{\sum_{k=1}^{n} \xi_{n,k}^2} \xrightarrow{p}{0} \quad \text{as} \quad n \to \infty$$

Then the following self-normalized random variable is asymptotically normally distributed:

$$\frac{\sum_{k=1}^{n} \xi_{n,k}}{\sqrt{\sum_{k=1}^{n} \xi_{n,k}^2}} \xrightarrow{d} \mathcal{N}(0,1)$$

**Question:** Is this theorem true? If not, what other conditions must be satisfied?